# how to apply the genetic algorithm to reduce the attributes in data set

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm, rapidminer

I have a data set with 10 attributes, then I want to reduce attributes in the data set for that I want to apply genetic algorithm, but I have a little bit confused on that concept so can you please give me any example.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to select only the most relevant attributes, you can most certainly rely on genetic algorithms where your genetic representation (also "genetic code" or "chromosomes") is a binary string. That means a certain attribute can either be present (selected) or not present (not selected).

Your genetic code will indeed be a binary string of length 10 and you can select the optimal set of attributes by running the following loop:

1. Import original dataset
2. Select important features from the dataset (given by the genetic code)
3. Shrink your dataset (imported in step #1) according to the selected features in step #2 (*)
4. Train and predict your classifier
5. Evaluate the fitness function (e.g. the error rate)
6. Go to step #2 until convergence (i.e. a maximum number of generations has been created)

So what the GA does, in more practical terms, is to create a first population of `N` individuals. For each individual, since this is the first population, the genetic code is purely random by default in Matlab (or you can write a function that explains how to select the initial population) and for each individual the steps #3, #4 and #5 are evaluated. Once every individual is matched with a certain fitness value, the GA creates the next generation (i.e. the genetic codes for the individuals in the next generation) by means of genetic operators (mainly crossover, elitism and selection). For the next generation individuals, such genetic codes are evaluated starting from the "best" (i.e. lowest fitness value if your problem is a minimization problem) individuals in the previous generation. You might want to check the genetic operators and how do they work for a better understanding of this "reproductive" process.

If you're using the `ga()` function in Matlab then input parameter `nvars` will be equal to 10; the `IntCon` parameter will have value `[1:10]` because you want all of them to be either 0 or 1; and the input parameter `option`, which is output of the function `gaoptimset()` will have the following parameters: upper bounds is a vector with 10 ones whereas lower bounds is a vector with 10 zeros. The `ga()` function treats your problem as a minimization problem, so I'd suggest to use the error rate as fitness function (or something else that you aim at minimizing).
To specify a binary population you can as well rely on the `PopulationType` input in `gaoptimset()`, but I never used it so I recommend you to read the help for this function (with `gaoptimset()` you can as well specify the number of individuals in your population and the number of generation that the GA will create before stopping...and many other parameters!).

(*) Note: *shrinking the dataset* does not necessarily mean you actually remove the columns (attributes) marked as `0` by your genetic algorithm. This will likely mess up your dissimilarity/distance evaluation between patterns. You can use the genetic code as a weight for your patterns when evaluating the dissimilarity measure: 10-features pattern element-wise multiplied by the 10-bits genetic code and the features that will be multiplied by zero will not have any importance (weight) in the dissimilarity measure.

Answer (score 0):

RapidMiner Studio comes with some genetic algorithm samples in the default repository.

//Samples/processes/04_Attributes/10_EvolutionaryFeatureSelection
//Samples/processes/04_Attributes/12_EvolutionaryWeighting
//Samples/processes/06_Meta/06_EvolutionaryParameterOptimization

The `Optimize Selection (Evolutionary)` operator is probably the operator to use. If you view the help for this operator, it is possible to load an example process from there. This process selects the best attributes to maximize the performance of a classification model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Binary Genetic Algorithm Feature Selection for your problem.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46961-binary-genetic-algorithm-feature-selection-zip

Maybe this File will help you on your problem. They even include their paper on the codes for further understanding.